# See all missing references in VS solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Does anyone know of a way to easily see all the missing references in all the projects of a solution?

I have a solution with lots of projects and because of missing references it is not building.
So there are lots of errors in the Error List but I can't see at a glance where all the missing references are.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stumbled across the information I was looking for in Visual Studio.
Thought I'd post the answer just in case it helps someone in the future.

To see all the missing references in a solution:

1. Go to the Error List (View > Error List)
2. View the Warnings
3. Any missing references will be displayed here as a warning - "The referenced component 'MyProject' could not be found"
4. The Warnings have a column "Project", so you can see at a glance which project(s) are missing references.